# Matlab R2014B on Ubuntu 14.04: paths do not match pathdef.m

Tags: matlab, path, installation

I have a frustrating problem - I purchased a new laptop and for some reason, no matter what my pathdef.m file (which is located in Matlab home) says, only the default paths are selected when I start up.  I can then select the paths I need and use them during the session, but this is somewhat time consuming as I use proprietary software and there are some 20 paths I need to define.

Has anyone encountered this problem or know of a workaround?  My pathdef.m file lists the paths I have previously selected in the standard manner.

Which pathdef returns the pathdef file containing the proper paths.

Comment: You should probably add your path in `startup.m`, or in `matlabrc.m` if needed, but not in `pathdef.m`

Comment: Looks like something funky is going on there, but I can fix it with matlabpath(pathdef) upon startup.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  This doesn't solve the problem, but it's a minimal burden to invoke this command on startup.

Comment: Why not just include the necessary `addpath` commands within `startup.m`?